# How to reach the parent folder with Ant

Tags: ant

I have these path I receive from an application :

```
D:\bamboo\remoteagent_prod\xml-data\build-dir\STUDIO-STUDIO-MYJOB
```

I have want to delete all files containing in

```
D:\bamboo\remoteagent_prod\xml-data\build-dir\
```

So I have to reach the parent folder.

That's what I have `D:\....\build-dir\STUDIO-STUDIO-MYJOB`  and that's what I want `D:\....\build-dir\`.

How can I do that with ANT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<property name="path" location="D:/temp/any"/>
<property name="parent.path" location="${path}/.."/>
<echo message="path: ${path}; parent: ${parent.path}" />
```

Creates the output:

> [echo] path: D:\temp\any; parent: D:\temp